# How to add html to the page inside a Razor if statement in a foreach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add html to the page from inside an `if()` in a `@foreach()`. I get dont get any specific error it just does not take the second `if()`. It writes it out like text.

this is what i tried but with no luck

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (count % 4 == 0 || totaltCount == 1)
        {
        <div class="in-instructor-container">
            }
            <div class="in-instructor">
                <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                @item.Information
            </div>
        if ((count - 1) % 3 == 0 || count == totaltCount) {
        </div>
        }

        count++;
    }
```

my html get like this

```
        <div class="in-instructor-container">
            }
            <div class="in-instructor">

                <h3>Test Person 0</h3>
                bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
            </div>
        if ((count - 1) % 3 == 0 || count == totaltCount) {
        </div>
```

Comment: I wasnt the one that down-voted you, but without more information you arent going to get any help. Was there an error? What was the issue?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to add @: in front of the html inside the if statements:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (count % 4 == 0 || totaltCount == 1)
    {
        // Single line html
        @:<div class="in-instructor-container">

        // Multi-line html
        <text>
            Your html code here
        </text>
    }

    <div class="in-instructor">
        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
        @item.Information
    </div>
    
    if ((count - 1) % 3 == 0 || count == totaltCount) {
        @:</div>
    }

    count++;
}
```

I found this solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5733885/2486) stackoverflow question

Comment: I'd upvote this a million times if I could as there were so many more answers on stackoverflow that were incorrect for this issue

Comment: Im think , The second condition must be => if (((count + 1) % 4 == 0) || count == totaltCount)

Comment: This really a good answer but i have 1 question on top of that. My question is how to add a multi line html after @:...?

Comment: @ManjunathaDL I haved added an example of multi-line html.